# Retrieving session data within Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, frameworks

I am creating an application which requires a login. The user is able to login, and the application will identify if the user has entered the correct credentials. From here the user will be presented with a dashboard containing information specific to them.

Once a user has entered the correct details, the following code executes:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
```

The application will direct the user to the correct location, which contains the following code:

```
$this->load->library('session');
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

This will display the standard session information (session_id, ip_address etc.), but the data in which I stored is not shown.

How do I go about fixing this so that this session data is accessible on every page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here are the current settings for sessions/cookies in config.php:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: This appears to be a common issue. I have given up on using the Codeigniter session functionality, and am going to use `$_SESSION` instead. Please continue leaving suggestions here, as I do want a proper solution!

Comment: weird issue, do you use db for session ? can you post the session and cookie config ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried storing the session with and without a database, and get the same results either way. I've added my config settings above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log in to the controller, and if you are using CodeIgniter 2, you need to set sessions on the database:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE; // Change FALSE TO TRUE
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'database',
    'session'
);
```

**In config/config.php, enter your own encryption_key**

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'FN3ig7JhmCeE9mWFc1BOetIt603qcr81';
```

Login

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('common/login_view');
    }
    else {
        $set_userdata = array(
            'is_logged' => true,
            'username' => $this->input->post('username')
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($set_userdata);
        redirect('success_page');
    }
}
```

On your parent part of controller.

```
<?php
    class dashboard extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged') == FALSE) {
                redirect('your error page or login');
            }
        }

        public function index() {

        }
    }
```

View Dashboard

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); ?>
</pre>

Single
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>
```

I would recommend using CodeIgniter 3 now, http://www.codeigniter.com/.

The other option is you could create a core/MY_Controller.php file:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged') == FALSE) {
            redirect('your error page or login');
        }
    }
}
```

And then extend the controller you need sessions enabled:

```
<?php
    class dashboard extends MY_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Some of the sample PHP code seems to be missing the ending "?>" (after starting out with "<?php").

Answer (score 0):

Setting up data in session:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
```

For print data `$this->session->userdata`

```
$this->load->library('session');
print_r($this->session->userdata); // For all userdata sessions
echo $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); // For a single value in a session with a key
```

Comment: `$this->session->userdata` seems to return the same as `all_userdata()`. Using `userdata('logged_in')` returns a false boolean.

Comment: it's just displaying what you set

Comment: well, he is setting a true value

Comment: try with TRUE rather true

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter sessions work; it's another issue. **In config/config.php**,

**change**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

**to**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
```

or

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'chocolatechipsinyourcookies';
```

The point is to **eliminate the underscore in the cookie name**. It can cause issues.

And now, in file config/autoload.php, around line 56, **autoload the session and database libraries**:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

This saves some code, and it assures that the session is being loaded first.